# Left align columns in bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am working in my redirect links section

I am trying to align my columns to the far left and far right so that they are even with the image above them.  I am setting the padding left to 0 on left most column and setting padding right to 0 on the right most column.  This seems to change the height of the middle column.  I have tried removing padding on left and right side of my center column but it still seems to change the height.

My goal is to get all 3 columns to look the same but be even with above image outer limits.  Hope this makes sense.

Link to codepen.
https://codepen.io/MikeBeers/pen/GerLKE

```
>

    <div class="container-fluid py-3">
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 pl-0">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x600.png" alt="" class="img-fluid rounded">
                <h2>Description 1</h2>
                <p class="text-muted">
```

Comment: Quoted from [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/overview/#containers):`While containers can be nested, most layouts do not require a nested container.`. Your example doesn't need nested `container-fluid`. So, you can remove `container-fluid` with any other horizontal padding classes from the banner `hero` div and the div below it, and the code would work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is to remove the padding from your container-fluid div:

```
.container-fluid {
  padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your container-fluid is stacking padding with your column boxes. Add 'pl-0 pr-0'to your container wrapper for the boxes and the elements will share the same gutter.